# Process finished with exit code 245

Tags: python

Ubuntu 18.04

Python 3.7.3

Django==2.2.3

The stack trace:

```
pydev debugger: process 20074 is connecting

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 31, 2019 - 14:28:33
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'ads_manager.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /]
[31/Aug/2019 14:30:22] "GET /] HTTP/1.1" 404 9405
[31/Aug/2019 14:30:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4908
[31/Aug/2019 14:30:24] "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)

Process finished with exit code 245
```

Several http requests are made in a loop. In other words, this function was called several times:

```
import requests
def execute_request(ad_entity, data, url=None):
    data_bytes = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")

    headers = get_headers()

    URL = url or '{}{}/'.format(API_ADDRESS, ad_entity.value.lower())

    response = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, data=data_bytes,
                             verify=False)
```

The problem seems to have something with thread safety in python itself. It doesn't seem to have something with Django. I tried to solve it by adding sleep up to 2 seconds between requests. It didn't help as far as I can see to the best of my ability.

Could you give me a kick here:
1. What does this code mean and where to read about it?
2. Is there any solution to this problem? 
3. Can I switch on a more elaborate logging or find  a more in-depth log somewhere?
4. Anyway, how to localize this problem?

Comment: Do not use `verify=False`. Yes, it's easy, and it "makes things work", but it does that by giving up the security that's the whole point of using SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are coming from the [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) module due to the HTTPS certificate verification being disabled.

The part responsible for that would be the `verify=False` to fix it simply remove it or replace it by `verify=True` (default)

Another way to suppress the warnings (*highly not recommended*) would be to add the following before importing requests:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```