# I keep getting Process finished with exit code 245 and flask crashes

Tags: python, macos, flask

I'm running a flask app in debug mode on macOS. The app runs fine but sometimes (and sometimes not) flask crashes and I get the following problem report below.

Versions:

```
macOS Monterey 12.3.1
python         3.10.4
flask          2.0.3
```

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739139/process-finished-with-exit-code-245) I tried the below and it doesn't work.

```
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Problem report

---

### Full Report

```
{"app_name":"Python","timestamp":"2022-05-05 06:11:05.00 +0200","app_version":"3.10.4","slice_uuid":"d5bf7fcc-187f-343b-9ca4-33ab5781fd97","build_version":"3.10.4","platform":1,"bundleID":"org.python.python","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)","incident_id":"F1B68122-59AC-4EDE-937C-747112F4F676","name":"Python"}
{
  "uptime" : 20000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-05-05 06:08:42.4689 +0200",
  "procRole" : "Unspecified",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro12,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 20492716809435,
  "coalitionID" : 946,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.3.1",
    "build" : "21E258",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-05-05 06:11:04.5897 +0200",
  "incident" : "F1B68122-59AC-4EDE-937C-747112F4F676",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 6040,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 20634831682639,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "Python",
  "procPath" : "\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/python@3.10\/3.10.4\/Frameworks\/Python.framework\/Versions\/3.10\/Resources\/Python.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Python",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"3.10.4","CFBundleVersion":"3.10.4","CFBundleIdentifier":"org.python.python"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"363B4C4C-1D11-5042-9FA0-D95755101537","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "Python",
  "parentPid" : 6029,
  "coalitionName" : "com.jetbrains.pycharm",
  "crashReporterKey" : "CF22B9B6-CBD2-8B32-93C2-AF141D16E647",
  "responsiblePid" : 931,
  "responsibleProc" : "pycharm",
  "wakeTime" : 20451,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "5B3E75E4-6108-4B1A-BADA-C7AB429E72DF",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "vmRegionInfo" : "0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4313341936\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      __TEXT                      101186000-10118a000    [   16K] r-x\/r-x SM=COW  ...\/MacOS\/Python",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000010","rawCodes":[1,16],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGSEGV","subtype":"KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":11,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Segmentation fault: 11","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":6040},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4313341936\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      __TEXT                      101186000-10118a000    [   16K] r-x\/r-x SM=COW  ...\/MacOS\/Python",
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 5,
  "threads" : [{"id":152527,"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":17386,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27247,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1249,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":48290,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":18,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":14113403,"symbol":"arrow::internal::ThreadPool::Shutdown(bool)","symbolLocation":251,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":14112971,"symbol":"arrow::internal::ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()","symbolLocation":43,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":14113774,"symbol":"arrow::internal::ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()","symbolLocation":14,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":123393,"symbol":"std::__1::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>::~shared_ptr()","symbolLocation":49,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":191956,"symbol":"__cxa_finalize_ranges","symbolLocation":409,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":191470,"symbol":"exit","symbolLocation":35,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":25461,"symbol":"dyld4::LibSystemHelpers::exit(int) const","symbolLocation":11,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":21832,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":504,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":152579,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":152677,"frames":[{"imageOffset":17386,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27247,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1249,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":48290,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":18,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":14146739,"symbol":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, arrow::internal::ThreadPool::LaunchWorkersUnlocked(int)::$_3> >(void*)","symbolLocation":947,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25825,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8043,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":152678,"frames":[{"imageOffset":17386,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27247,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1249,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":48290,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":18,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":14146739,"symbol":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, arrow::internal::ThreadPool::LaunchWorkersUnlocked(int)::$_3> >(void*)","symbolLocation":947,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25825,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8043,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":152679,"frames":[{"imageOffset":17386,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27247,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1249,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":48290,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":18,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":14146739,"symbol":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, arrow::internal::ThreadPool::LaunchWorkersUnlocked(int)::$_3> >(void*)","symbolLocation":947,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25825,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8043,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"triggered":true,"id":152692,"instructionState":{"instructionStream":{"bytes":[246,117,40,72,139,131,64,5,0,0,235,167,72,255,15,117,232,72,139,71,8,255,80,48,235,223,73,255,15,117,223,73,139,71,8,76,137,255,255,80,48,235,211,73,255,14,117,211,73,139,70,8,76,137,247,255,80,48,235,199,85,72,137,229,190,1,0,0,0,93,233,0,0,0,0,85,72,137,229,65,87,65,86,65,84,83,72,131,236,16,65,137,247,73,137,254,76,139,103,16,72,139,61,232,167,19,0,190,24,1,0,0,255,21,229,167,19,0,72,137,195,49,192,72,133,219,15,132,48,1,0,0,76,137,115,16,72,141,139,8,1,0,0,137,131,8,1,0,0,15,87,192,15,17,67,24,72,137,67,40,72,137,75,48,137,131,160,0,0,0,72,137,131,168,0,0,0,128,61,115,197,21,0,0,15,132,250,0,0,0,232,10],"offset":96}},"threadState":{"r13":{"value":123145558695736},"rax":{"value":0},"rflags":{"value":66050},"cpu":{"value":2},"r14":{"value":0},"rsi":{"value":1},"r8":{"value":16224},"cr2":{"value":16},"rdx":{"value":1674113532},"r10":{"value":2043},"r9":{"value":32},"r15":{"value":1},"rbx":{"value":105553162584704},"trap":{"value":14,"description":"(no mapping for user data read)"},"err":{"value":4},"r11":{"value":511},"rip":{"value":4319796901,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"rbp":{"value":123145558694928},"rsp":{"value":123145558694880},"r12":{"value":105553162584704},"rcx":{"value":0},"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rdi":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":1781413,"symbol":"new_threadstate","symbolLocation":21,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1784597,"symbol":"PyGILState_Ensure","symbolLocation":70,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":228324,"symbol":"arrow::py::PyBuffer::~PyBuffer()","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":228702,"symbol":"arrow::py::PyBuffer::~PyBuffer()","symbolLocation":14,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":123769,"symbol":"arrow::Result<std::__1::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> >::~Result()","symbolLocation":57,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":129667,"symbol":"arrow::Future<std::__1::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer> >::SetResult(arrow::Result<std::__1::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer> >)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*)","symbolLocation":19,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":14332964,"symbol":"arrow::ConcreteFutureImpl::~ConcreteFutureImpl()","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":14794878,"symbol":"arrow::io::internal::ReadRangeCache::Impl::~Impl()","symbolLocation":110,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":14789982,"symbol":"arrow::io::internal::ReadRangeCache::Impl::~Impl()","symbolLocation":14,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":743822,"symbol":"parquet::SerializedFile::~SerializedFile()","symbolLocation":494,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":742782,"symbol":"parquet::SerializedFile::~SerializedFile()","symbolLocation":14,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":1323295,"symbol":"parquet::arrow::(anonymous namespace)::FileReaderImpl::~FileReaderImpl()","symbolLocation":143,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":1441337,"symbol":"arrow::internal::FnOnce<void (arrow::FutureImpl const&)>::FnImpl<arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>::WrapResultyOnComplete::Callback<arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>::ThenOnComplete<parquet::arrow::RowGroupGenerator::operator()()::'lambda'(), arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>::PassthruOnFailure<parquet::arrow::RowGroupGenerator::operator()()::'lambda'()> > > >::~FnImpl()","symbolLocation":105,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":14333485,"symbol":"arrow::ConcreteFutureImpl::DoMarkFinishedOrFailed(arrow::FutureState)","symbolLocation":205,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":760792,"symbol":"arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>::DoMarkFinished(arrow::Result<arrow::internal::Empty>)","symbolLocation":152,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":760209,"symbol":"void arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>::MarkFinished<arrow::internal::Empty, void>(arrow::Status)","symbolLocation":81,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":1437126,"symbol":"arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty> arrow::internal::Executor::DoTransfer<arrow::internal::Empty, arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>, arrow::Status>(arrow::Future<arrow::internal::Empty>, bool)::'lambda'(arrow::Status const&)::operator()(arrow::Status const&)","symbolLocation":102,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":14335488,"symbol":"arrow::internal::FnOnce<void ()>::FnImpl<arrow::ConcreteFutureImpl::RunOrScheduleCallback(std::__1::shared_ptr<arrow::FutureImpl> const&, arrow::FutureImpl::CallbackRecord&&, bool)::CallbackTask>::invoke()","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":14146501,"symbol":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, arrow::internal::ThreadPool::LaunchWorkersUnlocked(int)::$_3> >(void*)","symbolLocation":709,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":25825,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8043,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":153415,"frames":[{"imageOffset":20238,"symbol":"__recvfrom","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":40967,"symbol":"sock_recv_impl","symbolLocation":27,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":38218,"symbol":"sock_call_ex","symbolLocation":166,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":40913,"symbol":"sock_recv_guts","symbolLocation":58,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":31770,"symbol":"sock_recv_into","symbolLocation":194,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":497213,"symbol":"method_vectorcall_VARARGS_KEYWORDS","symbolLocation":179,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":451802,"symbol":"PyObject_VectorcallMethod","symbolLocation":138,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2294108,"symbol":"_bufferedreader_raw_read","symbolLocation":173,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2293911,"symbol":"_bufferedreader_fill_buffer","symbolLocation":51,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2292468,"symbol":"_buffered_readline","symbolLocation":410,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":496998,"symbol":"method_vectorcall_FASTCALL","symbolLocation":95,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1441089,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":28216,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":445228,"symbol":"_PyObject_FastCallDictTstate","symbolLocation":87,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":910398,"symbol":"slot_tp_init","symbolLocation":200,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":876869,"symbol":"type_call","symbolLocation":275,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":444680,"symbol":"_PyObject_MakeTpCall","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473410,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":279,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1441089,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":28216,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":458359,"symbol":"method_vectorcall","symbolLocation":365,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1416159,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":3286,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1473289,"symbol":"call_function","symbolLocation":158,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1435440,"symbol":"_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault","symbolLocation":22567,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1408055,"symbol":"_PyEval_Vector","symbolLocation":342,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":458475,"symbol":"method_vectorcall","symbolLocation":481,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2235443,"symbol":"thread_run","symbolLocation":119,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1858765,"symbol":"pythread_wrapper","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":25825,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8043,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":153431,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703163707392,
    "size" : 229376,
    "uuid" : "26a59789-b846-3ed4-96dc-8dbef3c0c8e7",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703163936768,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "2f6c275d-7e14-3d31-a924-e1bb41d2415f",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703163252736,
    "size" : 364544,
    "uuid" : "94af60f2-7351-357d-8d33-d1b719c36a95",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++.1.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++.1.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4579696640,
    "size" : 28098560,
    "uuid" : "66d2e82f-459b-34af-8757-f96e6603e8d5",
    "path" : "\/usr\/local\/lib\/python3.10\/site-packages\/pyarrow\/libarrow.700.dylib",
    "name" : "libarrow.700.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703162691584,
    "size" : 561152,
    "uuid" : "8e54eca2-9bd8-3482-9589-b9574434d1aa",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703163985920,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "6627654a-f427-3e04-98ac-492a1ca26fcc",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdyld.dylib",
    "name" : "libdyld.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4488167424,
    "size" : 442368,
    "uuid" : "dd9e80de-fb3b-349b-96a4-46874ad34d11",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4318015488,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "3.10.4, (c) 2001-2021 Python Software Foundation.",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "org.python.python",
    "size" : 2965504,
    "uuid" : "d7cc2825-5a3c-3e55-8517-179a8443976f",
    "path" : "\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/python@3.10\/3.10.4\/Frameworks\/Python.framework\/Versions\/3.10\/Python",
    "name" : "Python",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "3.10.4"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4539133952,
    "size" : 1064960,
    "uuid" : "3283b18e-8227-350b-a87b-67dff4f3fe29",
    "path" : "\/usr\/local\/lib\/python3.10\/site-packages\/pyarrow\/libarrow_python.700.dylib",
    "name" : "libarrow_python.700.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4575506432,
    "size" : 2048000,
    "uuid" : "d50f8e42-4a84-3f75-a743-3441add3b115",
    "path" : "\/usr\/local\/lib\/python3.10\/site-packages\/pyarrow\/libparquet.700.dylib",
    "name" : "libparquet.700.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4374605824,
    "size" : 65536,
    "uuid" : "078ee034-1c67-36f7-a78d-6cc4c5876b56",
    "path" : "\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/python@3.10\/3.10.4\/Frameworks\/Python.framework\/Versions\/3.10\/lib\/python3.10\/lib-dynload\/_socket.cpython-310-darwin.so",
    "name" : "_socket.cpython-310-darwin.so"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 140703160664064,
  "size" : 15224815616,
  "uuid" : "6cc5ecdc-5119-37f0-9a85-4f48a50f5f78"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=559.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=559.9M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=1.9G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.9G(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nIOAccelerator                      1.0G       10 \nKernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 \nMALLOC                           270.3M       48 \nMALLOC guard page                   16K        4 \nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                         32K        8 \nStack                             35.1M       11 \nVM_ALLOCATE                      192.0M      128 \n__DATA                            9354K      280 \n__DATA_CONST                      6268K      137 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       211K       51 \n__LINKEDIT                       349.7M      143 \n__OBJC_RO                         82.6M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3200K        2 \n__TEXT                           210.2M      270 \n__UNICODE                          592K        1 \ndyld private memory               1104K        3 \nshared memory                       12K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              2.5G     1101 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.1G     1101 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "61af99aeda72d16a4beb7756",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000144
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000140
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM 428.60.3.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1710.3)
AirPort: 
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB30Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that gets here via Pycharm, a workaround is to set

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
```

in the env vars in pycharm. Or elsewhere I guess should also work.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I set the Environment variable in the run configuration I was using to start the app in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: run without pycharm debugger

I got exit code 245 when running multi threaded version with Pycharm debugger. With `--nothreading` I get `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)` and with `PYTHONDEVMODE=1` environment variable the stack points to some very basic python code.

When I put a breakpoint at that line and step over it everything works as intended.

Running straight from the commandline (in Pycharm) works fine.

Jetbrains command for debugging is `/path-to/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/222.4167.33/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 37627 --file /path-to/manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload` I'm not sure if Alpine CI does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same "finished with exit code 245" on Ubuntu with Python 3.10.4 with Pycharm Community Edition in debug mode. I switched to Python 3.9.12 and problem went away.

Edit: Daniel Lee's answer above also worked. I set `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO` in `Environment variables` in the run configuration I was using to run the app in debug mode.

Comment: It might be a pycharm - python3.10 problem

Comment: I don't think it's related to PyCharm, because we got it on an Alpine CI machine also, during a test.